# Proper way to secure a basement post to a metal I-beam

Tags: basement, beam, column

A home inspection noted that the center beam in our basement was not secured.

[image]

What is required to secure a beam to a column, and is it really required?

The house is in Oakland Co, Michigan, so not a lot of earthquakes there.

Answer (score 4):

Some are welded, by bending those "ears" or "tabs" over, others are bolted with clamps using those tabs.

Check what was specified with the architect / design engineer.

And, YES, it is required, otherwise it could be knocked over...

Comment: It's also common to see holes drilled in the beam flange for mounting hardware, so you may be able to use the holes in the post flange and just pop in two bolts. That may be the simplest and cheapest solution. Do check specs, though.

Comment: In Maryland, the ears were only needed to be bent over. If Michigan has the same seismic requirements, that is all you may need, that is if it hasn't changed over the years. Bolting is the simplest DIY fix, Welding is great too, but a little more difficult to do yourself.

Comment: @Jack Just bending the ears over would only keep the post from sliding in one direction.

Comment: @LeeSam That is true, and I should have addressed the whole situation where the bottom of the post is cast in 8" of concrete with the bottom of the post bearing on a pier footing, and the floor slab is thickened at the footings and edges. There may have been another fastening method but I don't recall seeing it done. This was 35-40 years ago or so. At least that is how my cousin did it who taught me the trade. He was a GC, building single family homes and additions, and anything else that kept us working.

Answer (score 0):

Simpson makes a column cap, but you’d need to cut the top flange off.

Here’s their catalog showing different sizes:

https://www.strongtie.com/lallysteelcolumncaps_columncaps/lcc-ccos_productgroup_wcc/p/lcc.ccos

Comment: That's for wood beams.  Note teensy weensy nail holes.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Oops...you’re right.